# In stock products in category

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to display products in a particular category whose quantity is 1 or more. Please help me in getting done.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file in this location (replace XXX/YYY with your theme location);

```
app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/template/catalog/product/instock.phtml
```

In this file put this;

```
<?php

$instockIds = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
->getCollection()
->addQtyFilter('>=', 1);

foreach($instockIds as $stock) {
    $idarray[] = $stock->getProductId();
}

// Get all products
// $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

// Load just 1 category, set the ID here
$categoryId = 12;
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($idarray)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

//Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($_productCollection);

$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

$toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')->getToolbarBlock();
$pager = $layout->createBlock('page/html_pager');
$block = $layout->createBlock('catalog/product_list');

$toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);
$toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);
$toolbar->setPageSize(10);
$toolbar->setCurPage(1);
$toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);

$block->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
$block->setCollection($_productCollection);
$block->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');

echo $block->renderView();
```

Now create a cms page, set the design of your page to match your category default - 2 column left etc.

In the content of the page, put this;

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/instock.phtml"}}
```

This will load all products that either have stock, or are set to not manage stock.

Comment: I want it for particular category, like based on category id.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to do display product based on stock count, like if stock product quantity is greater than zero, only those products have to be displayed.

Comment: This will only show products that have stock OR are set to not manage stock.  As long as you are managing stock, then this will only show the ones with stock.

Comment: By default all the products are in stock, for few of the products quantity is added. I want to display those products from category to which quantity is added. So i was asking for product quantity greater than 0.